# Acrobat Form: Setting a Default Selection Based on another Field

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, acrobat

I'm working in Adobe Acrobat on a PDF Form. I have 4 combo boxes that have identical values available. Each field can be different from the others, but it is often likely that they are the same. Once a selection is made on Item 1, I'd like to have Items 2-4 make the same selection, while still allowing the user to be able to select an item from the original list.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Testing for understanding... the first time the user selects from Item 1, the other three values get set. What do you want to happen if they change a value in Item 2, 3 or 4 and then go back to Item 1 and change it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'd like if they go back to change item 1, that 2-4 didn't change, but I know that may not be possible.

As an example, each drop down has something like: Standard, Blank, Baffle, Comb.If they pick Standard on Item 1, it's likely that items 2-4 are also standard. By prefilling them it reduces data entry. But I still want them to be able to edit the content. 

I also thought a checkbox like you see for billing and shipping addresses might work. They could click it if all the other items are the same to prefill. But they are combo boxes, and not fill-in.

Comment: It's possible. Give me day or two to work it out though.